# How to copy a file from AWS rest API gateway to s3 bucket?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Using an API gateway, I created an S3 bucket to copy an image (image/jpg). This website describes how I can upload images using Amazon's API gateway: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/.

When I type the URL by adding the bucket and object name, I get the following error:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

I would like to know, first of all, where API can find my image? How can I verify that the image is a local file as stated in the introduction? In addition to that, should I use the curl command to complete the transformation? I am unable to use Potsman.

I have included a note from the link, how can I change the type of header in a put request?

What is the best way to copy files from the API gateway to S3 without using the Lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set up your API and bucket following the instructions in the link, you upload a local file to your bucket using curl command as below.

**curl -X PUT -H "Accept: image/jpeg" https://my-api-id.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/my-stage-name/my-bucket-name/my-local-file.jpg**

Note that the header indicates it will accept jpeg files only. Depending on the file you are uploading to S3, you will change/add this header.

To answer the questions directly:
What is the best way to copy files from the API gateway to S3 without using the Lambda function? - *follow steps in this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/*

where API can find my image? - *your image is located in your local host/computer. You use curl command to upload it via the API that you created*

should I use the curl command to complete the transformation? - *not sure what you meant by transformation. But you use curl command to upload the image file to your S3 bucket via API Gateway*

how can I change the type of header in a put request? - *you use -H to add headers in your curl command*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, where should I put this code in the API gateway? PUT /v1/s3?key=image.jpg HTTP/1.1 Host: abcdefghi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com Content-Type: application/octet-stream Accept: application/json

[raw bytes]

Comment: It's a curl command. Assuming you had completed the steps to setup your API and your bucket from the link. The actual command is below. I just tested it with my own setup and it works. The .jpg file is located in my local host where I'm executing the curl command.

curl -X PUT -H "Accept: image/jpeg" https://my-api-id.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Dev/jsqcloud/pexels-pixabay-2150.jpg

Comment: I appreciate you sending me the link, but it seems it is not working.

Comment: Did you follow the steps from the link? If yes, you have your API gateway integrated to the S3 bucket now, right? So now you can run the curl command. Change the api endpoint url and the bucket name, as well as the name of the file in your local host. And don't just say it's not working because I followed the exact same steps and it works. Give more details.

Comment: Do you have any example of the curl command that you used? In ubuntu system I used curl command, and I had the image in the directory, still it did not went through, by the link you mean the follwing link?